# Focused elements display wrong style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have element with width 400% and I want to move it to left by using translateX(-(index/4)*100%) when focused index changes.

Changing focused element translateX property with tab keyboard button displays it wrong on middle elements (1,2) even though using same hardcoded styling works as expected. What am I missing here?

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [curr, setCurr] = useState(0);
  const carouselStyles = {
    transform: `translateX(${-(curr / 4) * 100}%)`

    // uncomment to see that styling works fine with hardcoded values 1,2..
    // transform: `translateX(${-(1 / 4) * 100}%)`
  };

  const handleFocus = (num) => {
    if (num !== curr) {
      setCurr(num);
    }
  };

  console.log(carouselStyles);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="carousel" style={carouselStyles}>
        <div className="item">
          11 very long text
          <a href="/111" onFocus={() => handleFocus(0)}>
            11111
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="item">
          22 very long text
          <a href="/222" onFocus={() => handleFocus(1)}>
            22222
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="item">
          33 very long text
          <a href="/333" onFocus={() => handleFocus(2)}>
            33333
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="item">
          44 very long text
          <a href="/444" onFocus={() => handleFocus(3)}>
            44444
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      current: {curr}
    </div>
  );
}


// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400%;
}

.item {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: It doesn't, on first tab press It correctly focus 1 link but when you press tab second time It jumps to 3 link even though the 2 element is focused

Comment: Looks like this is what's happening: You tab to 2 which causes scrolling in the container, then you apply the transform, which changes where the element is so it's off to the left now. You'll want to prevent or undo the scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to prevent the scrolling and in my provided example its enough to add this line into handleFocus function

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

But in my real scenario parent wrapper also had `overflow: hidden;` which prevented above code from working. So I've used refs

```
const handleFocus = (num) => {
    if (num !== curr) {
      setCurr(num);
      carouselRef.current.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
};

return (
    <div ref={carouselRef}>
      <div className="carousel" style={carouselStyles}>
         ...
      </div>
      current: {curr}
    </div>
);
```